# Not able to use pivot in oracle SQL as coluns values are dynamic every time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot, transpose, dynamic-columns

I am not able convert the rows to columns.

For example:

```
SMS COUNT
---------------------
5090
4560
```

Above values are dynamic, may change dynamically.

Expected output:

Result should have to be in two different columns.

```
SMS COUNT.              VOICE COUNT
--------------------.   ---------------------
5090.                   4560
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT count() AS REPORT
  FROM VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT
  WHERE VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.DISE_MPN = VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.UDR_MPN
    AND (VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.DISE_DOM_ALLOWANCE <> VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.UDR_DOM_ALLOWANCE OR VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.DISE_DOM_ALLOWANCE IS NULL)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT count() AS REPORT
  FROM VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT
  WHERE VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.DISE_MPN = VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.UDR_MPN
) PIVOT (count(*) 
     FOR
     REPORT IN ('REPORT' Missing_in_UDR, 'REPORT' Missing_in_DISE));
```

Comment: Perhaps it would be nice if a table definition, some demo records and your attempts at the problem would be included in the post. And an actual question perhaps too.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Provide some sample data

Comment: select * from (select count(*) as REPORT from VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT Where  VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.DISE_MPN = VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.UDR_MPN And (VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.DISE_DOM_ALLOWANCE <> VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.UDR_DOM_ALLOWANCE Or VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.DISE_DOM_ALLOWANCE IS NULL) UNION ALL select count(*) as REPORT From VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT where VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.DISE_MPN = VIDS_DISE_SRM_UDR_REPORT.UDR_MPN) pivot ( count(*) for REPORT in ('REPORT' Missing_in_UDR, 'REPORT' Missing_in_DISE )) ; getting invalid number error.

Comment: first of all `count()` needs an argument in it, convert it to `to_char( count(*) ) as REPORT` within `..select count() as REPORT..` against invalid number error, and add `as` keyword within after `pivot` as `pivot ( count(*) for REPORT in ('REPORT' as Missing_in_UDR, 'REPORT' as Missing_in_DISE ))`